# wget - http://: Invalid host name

Tags: bash, shell, wget, hostname

I'm using wget to automatically download the ShellEd extension for Eclipse, but am receiving an error:

```
http://: Invalid host name.
```

I have used it successfully several times before, so I think it's because SourceForge uses a mirror.  I've looked at the [man page for wget](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_27.html), focusing on referer and http_proxy, but am still unsuccessful. Here is my script:

```
dowloadFile="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/Shelled%201.0.4/shelled_1_0_4.zip?use_mirror=voxel"
wget "$downloadFile"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible candidate for Superuser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it **dowloadFile** or **downloadFile** ? There's a discrepancy there

Answer (score 1):

I concur with pavium

```
$ wget  "$dowloadFile"
--2009-10-02 07:11:41--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/Shelled%201.0.4/shelled_1_0_4.zip?use_mirror=voxel
Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net... 216.34.181.59
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net|216.34.181.59|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/Shelled%201.0.4/shelled_1_0_4.zip [following]
--2009-10-02 07:11:41--  http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/project/shelled/shelled/Shelled%201.0.4/shelled_1_0_4.zip
Resolving voxel.dl.sourceforge.net... 72.26.192.194
Connecting to voxel.dl.sourceforge.net|72.26.192.194|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2020011 (1.9M) [application/zip]
Saving to: `shelled_1_0_4.zip.4'

100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 2,020,011   53.8K/s   in 37s

2009-10-02 07:12:18 (53.6 KB/s) - `shelled_1_0_4.zip.4' saved [2020011/2020011]
```